# Bootstrapでhover時に他のアイコンに変えたい

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hover時に1-circleから、1-circle-fillのアイコンに変えたいです。

下記のように記述したところ、画像のように黒色の四角形になってしまいます。
よろしくお願い致します。

```css
.header-icon .bi-i-circle:hover {
  font-family: 'Bootstrap-icons';
  content: '\F796';
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="header-icon">
  <a class="button" href="#"><i class="bi bi-1-circle"></i></a>
  <a class="button" href="#"><i class="bi bi-1-circle-fill"></i></a>
</div>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap Icons v1.9.1 を使われているようですが、[`bi-1-circle-fill`にはバグがあり](https://github.com/twbs/icons/issues/1385)、[v1.10.0で修正されています](https://github.com/twbs/icons/releases/tag/v1.10.0#:%7E:text=%231425%3A%20Adjust%20fill%2Drule%20of%201%2Dcircle%2Dfill)。v1.10.0以降を使いましょう。

加えて設定しているCSSセレクタも間違っています。まず、`bi-i-circle`（アイ）ではなく`bi-1-circle`（イチ）です。更に`::before`疑似要素の`content`スタイルを変更する必要があります。

```css
.header-icon .bi-1-circle:hover::before {
  content: '\F796';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="header-icon">
  <a class="button" href="#"><i class="bi bi-1-circle"></i></a>
  <a class="button" href="#"><i class="bi bi-1-circle-fill"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。::beforeにに対してスタイルの変更するのですね。
重ねて恐縮ですが、v1.10.0に変更したのですが、下記アイコンに関して修正ができないようでして。
<i class="bi bi-person"></i>からbi-person-fill
<i class="bi bi-bag"></i>からbi-bag-fill
先ほどと同様で-fillのついたアイコンにしたいのですが、他のアイコンでも同様に黒い四角形になってしまいます。
.bi-bag:hover::before{
  font-family:'Bootstrap-icons';
  content: '\F174';
  background-color: #000;
}
}

Comment: @pepe 「スニペットを実行」のボタンを押せれば **投稿された質問文** に対しては問題が解決していることはわかると思います。スタックオーバーフローは一問一答形式ですので、追加質問は別投稿としてください。その際、本スレッドを解決済みとしてください。

Comment: 失礼いたしました。ご教示頂きありがとうございました。